# How to fill polygons with unique color in python matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, polygon

Description: What I am trying to achieve is to create a map of Finland colored according to what Waste Management association is in charge of handling municipal waste in different regions.

Problem: There are like about 40 different waste management associations, but matplotlib uses only 10 different colors. Problem therefore is that some regions get the same color. I want all the regions to be differently colored.

This question has been asked in some variations before, but I haven't been able to successfully use those suggestions to solve my problem. Most suggestions I have found seem to be unnecessarily complicated for what I reckon should have a simple solution.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

url = "http://geo.stat.fi/geoserver/tilastointialueet/wfs?request=GetFeature&typename=tilastointialueet:kunta1000k&outputformat=JSON" #downloads the municipality polygon file
df1 = gpd.read_file(url)

url = "https://github.com/tomasstoras/wastemanagement/blob/main/wastemanagement.csv?raw=true"
df2 = pd.read_csv(url,encoding="UTF-8",delimiter=';') #download waste management information file

merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on = 'nimi', right_on = 'Kunta',how = 'outer') #merge polygon and waste management file

merged.fillna({x:0 for x in ['Avfallshanteringsverk','Kunta']}, inplace=True) #Clean up file

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(100,100))
merged.plot(column='Avfallshanteringsverk',  match_original=True, linewidth=1, ax=ax, edgecolor='0.9', legend=True)
ax.axis('off')
plt.show() #Plot result
```

[image: Image of result]

Comment: There is a physical limitation, as humans usually aren't able to easily distinguish and identify more than about 12 different colors. If you don't mind colors being close to each other, you can use something like `colors = plt.get_cmap('turbo`)(np.linspace(0,1,40))`.

Comment: @JohanC Thank you! That mostly did it. As some similar colors are still close together, do you know of any way where the colors stay the same, but you force a color for some certain values? E.g. "Kangasniemen Jätehuolto Oy" --> Red

Btw, I think, (np.linspace(0,1,40)) part of your code is broken.

Comment: My test code was missing a closing quote, and the import of numpy.  `import numpy as np; colors = plt.get_cmap('turbo')(np.linspace(0,1,40))` should work.  Note that `plt.get_cmap()` returns a function, which can be called on an array of equally spaced numbers.  You can use `np.random.shuffle()` to randomize the order.  You can also change a specific entry, e.g. `colors[0] = [1,0,0,1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cmap`, all that you would need in that case is a color dictionary, something like:

```
{0: (1.0, 1.0, 0.5),
 1: (0.98, 0.995, 0.499),
 2: (0.96, 0.99, 0.498),
etc
```

An example with mock data and pandas df, but cmap also works with geopandas:

```
# imports
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# vars
dlen = 400
dscalar = 0.04
rscalar = 0.02
gscalar = 0.005
bscalar = 0.001

# data and colors
dd = dict.fromkeys(range(dlen))
cd = dict.fromkeys(range(dlen))
for i in range(dlen):
    # data
    d = [1 + (i * dscalar), 2, 3 - (i * dscalar)]
    dd[i] = d
    # colors
    r = round(1 - (rscalar * i), 3)
    g = round(1 - (gscalar * i), 3)
    b = round(0.5 - (bscalar * i), 3)
    color = (r, g, b)
    cd[i] = color
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dd)
color_dict = cd

# plotting
df.plot(legend=True, cmap=colors.ListedColormap(list(color_dict.values())))
plt.show()

# alternative: color dict using get_cmap
cdget = plt.get_cmap("turbo")(np.linspace(0, 1, dlen))
color_dict = cdget
df.plot(legend=True, cmap=colors.ListedColormap(color_dict))
plt.show()
```

[Simple plot showing custom colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c56nT.png)